# Post build events in VS 2010 Express edition?

Tags: visual-studio

I have been using post build events in VS 2008 up until now, and downloaded the 2010 Express edition to check out the new features. In 2008, build events were in project properties>compile>build events.

I don't see that button in 2010 Express edition. Is that because it's not included in the Express edition or have they moved it?

Answer (score 1):

In my VS2010 Premium copy it is projectproperties>Build Events. If you don't have that, then I guess it isn't in the Express edition.

---

Best I can do on finding a cite, from [here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/Explorer/DevSetupPostBuildStep.html):

> The project-level options available in
>   the Visual Studio Project Designer
>   might differ from what is described
>   here depending on your active settings
>   or edition. Specifically, Express
>   editions do not provide a user
>   interface to set up or edit build
>   events, although existing events are
>   honored. See the Express Editions
>   section below for more information.

Comment: Presumably "existing events are honored" means you could edit the project file outside of Visual Studio to introduce them.  Fiddly, but easy enough if you can find a working example somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Express, but in VS 2010 Pro they're in **Project Properties / Configuration Properties / Build Events**.

Comment: Thanks chaps, i thought so. I have 2008 pro, so assumed they stripped it out for the express edition. 2010 looks pretty good so far, so it looks like i'll upgrade anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [How to: Specify Build Events (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7xctbe2f(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation page on MSDN, build events are not supported in the IDE in the Express edition. It contains the following note in the documentation:

> You cannot specify build events from the Visual Basic Express IDE.